# How SNMP agent gets data from snmp devices will work c#

Tags: snmp, snmp4j, snmpd, sharp-snmp

I've been looking around the net for a guide or tutorial on how to start on using C#.NET to query SNMP devices but I have been unsuccessful.

I am using Sharpsnmplib because of MIT license.

I didn't understand about the flow of data that how devices will communicate with SNMP agent, is there any event for which agent will listen. How devices send traps to agent and then to manager.

What is v1, v2c and v3.? Is this device configuration.

I guess I have to create some window service and periodically (timer based) execute SendTrapV1 method and in another service(SNMP manager) I have to listen to these traps.
[image]
My requirement is to identify the antenna level trap of Impinj Reader and have many SNMP devices in the network.

I have to implement also auto-discovers facility to discover SNMP devices installed in the network.

Any project or code will be helpful in this case.

Comment: Agents are on the devices themselves. Why couldn't you find a good enough book such as Essential SNMP before moving on?

Comment: @LexLi: That's mean, we don't have to create SNMP agent, Its on the device, we just to do only configuration that which type of trap we want to send. we just need to create SNMP manager which listens to all the devices.

Comment: @LexLi: Any Comment?

Comment: @ankitGupta : Did you get any solution for your question? Me also having the same requirement in c#